# First two lines of post disappeared from post list page

Tags: bug

I'm used to seeing the post list with the title and then two lines from the body of the post, like so:

[image: Screenshot of Meta]

I see Stack Overflow like that, too. But after doing some editing on a post, I went back to the list page and saw this:

[image: Screenshot from Stack Overflow]

I've noticed this before, but never like this, from going into a post to coming back to the list. The page didn't even refresh. I don't know that this is a bug, I just wanted you guys to know about it. I use those two lines from the post to determine whether I will edit a post, and not seeing those two lines is not helpful.

Comment: I just went back to Stack Overflow, and the two lines are back. ?

Comment: Are you on the new-nav? (Collapsed questions is a setting on the new-nav.) If so, you should add the new-nav tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ !== http://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: Agreed, @Rizier123, that's what I thought I'd gotten back to. But I was still on /questions. And kendra, I don't know if I have that.

Comment: Now the first two lines are gone everywhere.

Comment: If you are on the new nav, on all tabs but the home-tab, there's a button to switch between compact- and excerpt-view in the top-right, next to the question-count.

Comment: When on the Newest tab I can see the question count, and I found the two little buttons. I clicked the one that looked right, and there it was! That did it! I'll accept if you make it an answer, @Deduplicator.